# troubleshooting d3.js installation 'Let's Make a Map' tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am trying to begin Mike Bostock's ["Let's Make A Map" tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) but am running into basic installation issues upfront. I am running this on Windows 8.1. This is the part:

"Next you’ll need the reference implementation for TopoJSON, which requires Node.js. (You can install Node via Homebrew, but the official installers work just as well.) After installing Node, run the following to install TopoJSON:

npm install -g topojson

And to verify the two installations, try:

which ogr2ogr
 which topojson"

I installed node.js and figured out that I have to run the 'npm install -g topojson' command in cmd.exe. and not node.js, but I am having trouble with the 'which' commands and those following it. When I type the

```
which ogr2ogr
```

in my cmd.exe, it says 'which is not recognized as an internal or external command' and when I type it in node.js it says "Syntax error; unexpected identifier"

Help?

Answer (score 1):

`which` is a unix command that shows you where something is located on your filesystem.

You can check on windows if you have that command by just running `ogr2ogr` and see if it complains that the command exists or not

Comment: It complains that the command doesn't exist. Ideas about how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are German, but I created a German tutorial about installing topoJSON under Windows: [**TopoJSON unter Windows**](http://www.kwoxer.de/2015/01/26/topojson-contextify-node-gym-unter-windows-installieren-tutorial/) Maybe this helps.

And for sure you cannot use which under Windows. I also have many pictures in the tutorial if you are not German.

Comment: Thank you  for writing! I actually do know a little German :) Your tutorial has been very helpful but I am running into a couple problems.  1) I installed Visual Studio Express but when I tried to install the Visual Studio SP1 it told me "A compatible version of Visual Studio 2010 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010." 2) I am getting errors when trying to use node-gyp...when I type "node-gyp configure" it says "'node-gyp' is not recognized..." (Please let me know if I should put this in a different post). Vielen Dank!!

Comment: I don't think that you need that SP1 installed, did you try without?

Comment: Yes, then I get the problem with the node-gyp not being recognized and it doesn't work after you try to install contextify (the second time, when it should actually work...). Thank you for replying

Comment: And you did exactly what was told in the tutorial, like uninstalliing als VS stuff and so on? And is it a fresh system or maybe you have some other stuff installed that harms it? Maybe you ask Bostock because one year ago he said he is planning and easier installation on Windows systems. Maybe there is already something done in that way. Would be cool. =)

Comment: It is possible I have other programs installed, but I have no clue what they could be. I am going to try installing a VM with Linux and running it on there instead of Windows :(

Comment: Or makes it sense to upload my topojson folder. Will that work? =)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?